# R: logistic distribution with base 10 instead of e

Tags: r, distribution

I have been looking in google and documentation function like `plogis`, `dlogis`, which have in base not e but 10. Is something like this available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need another set of functions, since the transformation is trivial. The CDF for the logistic distribution with center mu and scale s is

F(x) = 1/(1+e^(-(x-mu)/s))

Let y=(x-mu)/s; then 10^y = e^(y*ln(10)), so you simply need to replace s by s/ln(10) to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: indeed trivial, why I haven't thought about it!